# Update variable outside of preg_replace_callback from within the callback

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

I have a function which looks something like this...

```
function filterwords($input='poo poo hello world bum trump'){

    $report_swear = 0;

    $badwords = array('poo','bum','trump');

    $filterCount = sizeof($badwords);

    for($i=0; $i<$filterCount; $i++){
            $input = preg_replace_callback('/\b'.preg_quote($badwords[$i]).'\b/i', function($matches) use ($report_swear) {
                $report_swear++;
                return str_repeat('*', 4);
            }, $input);
    }

    print_r($report_swear);

    return $input;

}
```

In this example I would expect the $report_swear variable to return 4 but it still returns 0.

Any idea how I alter this within the callback?

Thanks

Comment: You need to pass your variable by reference to change it out of the scope of your callback function.

Comment: Sounds like a plan, but how do I go about doing that?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php That's how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are exactly trying to do, but note that you can use the 4th parameter of `preg_replace_*` that is a counter. Instead of looping on all words you can build a pattern as an alternation *(the advantage is that your string is parsed only once, instead of once per word)*:

```
function filterwords($input='poo poo hello world bum trump'){
    $badwords = array('poo','bum','trump');
    $badwords = array_map('preg_quote', $badwords);
    $pattern = '/\b(?:' . implode('|', $badwords) . ')\b/i';

    $result = preg_replace($pattern, '****', $input, -1, $count);
    echo $count;
    return $result;
}
```

If you want to take in account the words length:

```
function filterwords($input='poo poo hello world bum trump'){
    $badwords = array('poo','bum','trump');
    $badwords = array_map('preg_quote', $badwords);
    $pattern = '/\b(?:' . implode('|', $badwords) . ')\b/i';

    $result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) {
        return str_repeat('*', strlen($m[0]));
    }, $input, -1, $count);
    echo $count;
    return $result;
}
```

Note: if your input string or your list of bad words contains unicode characters, you need to add the u modifier to your pattern and to use [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) in place of `strlen`. See the php manual for details.

Comment: For the record, relating to `array_map('preg_quote', $badwords)`, `preg_quote()` does not have `/` as the default delimiter.  In other words, if there is a slash in a word, it will not be escaped and will break the pattern.  This is a complaint that I have not formally brought to the PHP community.  I also find "preg_quote()` to be an unintuitive function name.  It should be `preg_escape()` and the function should have a default delimiter of the most common pattern delimiter -- `/`.